How can I connect to Bigquery in Airflow using an AWS federated token json?
I need to build an airflow connector that reads from google bigquery, despite being hosted on aws.
My devops team have created a secret json in the format of:
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": xx,
  "subject_token_type": xx,
  "service_account_impersonation_url": xx,
  "token_uri": xx,
  "credential_source": {xx, xx, xx}
}

which I believe corresponds to https://google.aip.dev/auth/4117
They have uploaded the secret to SSM as a parameter, which I am trying to pull using SsmHook.getparameter_value(). This may or not be working, but I have no idea how I can use this to set up the BigQueryGetDataOperator which seems need to be authenticated in another manner.
If I simply pull the secret and run the operator, my response is:
airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `google_cloud_default` isn't defined

Could anybody advise how best to continue given these infra restrictions? Thanks
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryGetDataOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.ssm import SsmHook

PROJECT = "xxx"
DATASET = "xxx"
TABLE = "xxx"


def get_ssm_parameter(parameter_name, with_decryption=True):
    hook = SsmHook()
    return hook.get_parameter_value(parameter_name, with_decryption)


def get_token():
    return get_ssm_parameter(
        parameter_name="/prod/xxx/airflow", with_decryption=True
    )


with DAG(
    "example-dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="read-bigquery",
        python_callable=get_token,
    )
    get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
        task_id="get_data",
        dataset_id=DATASET,
        table_id=TABLE,
        max_results=10,
    )
    end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")
    start >> t1 >> get_data >> end



You need to provide the parameter gcp_conn_id to BigQueryGetDataOperator because it will otherwise use google_cloud_default as a connection

Doesn't that imply that there is an airflow connection to bigquery? I am not able to set one up given the federated token does not contain a 'private key'

yes, you should be able to use a GCP Service Account in your connections, but first you might try to create the Service Account from your private key

So using an AWS federated token for BigQuery access, you cannot create a connection inside Airflow's UI, and therefore not use the BigQueryGetDataOperator. I found that as above, you can retrieve the token from ssm with the hook, and then to set it as environmental variable, you need to write it to a temp local file with :
token = arbitrary_get_token_func()
with open("/temp/token.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(token)
# this needs to be a path, not the file itself
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/tmp/token.json" 
os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = "{project-name}"

client = bigquery.Client()
rows = client.list_rows(f"{PROJECT}.{DATASET}.{TABLE}", max_results=xx) # to limit result size
return rows.to_dataframe() # or to_arrow() etc


